# Android performance multiple recyclerviews in overlaying fragments

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In our app we require that tapping a link in 1 recyclerview causes a new fragment (or activity) to appear and overlay and show a new recyclerview.
This creates a 'story' of recyclerviews that will become a fragment stack, where fragments will be popped of the stack when tapping 'back'.

An example is: 
Show feed -> Show user feed on tapping a user -> Show another user on tapping another user -> Show place feed on tapping a place -> ... etc ...

I'm concerned about performance.
In theory there won't be a limit to the number of overlaying fragments containing a recyclerview.
My question is:

1. Would you advice using overlay activities instead of fragments (although I actually have already a working prototype with fragments using FragmentManager);
2. More importantly: Is this solution viable on different Android devices, and should I limit the number of possible overlays. Is there an alternative solution for solving this?

The reason for having overlays is to provide best user experience: i.e. state of the previous feed is always kept, and displayed correctly instantly.

As an alternative solution I had in mind, I could save the different feeds locally in sqlite along with their states. But this requires images to be reloaded on every 'back' action.

What is your point of view for an optimal solution?

@jonathanrz

```
public void slideOpenOverlay(int fragmentContainer, Fragment fragment, String tag,
                         int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit){
    fm.beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(enter, exit, popEnter, popExit)
        .add(fragmentContainer, fragment, tag)
        .addToBackStack(tag)
        .commit();

}
```

Comment: You are adding the new fragment and keeping the old one in the screen? Can you post the code where you add the new fragment?

Comment: @jonathanrz Which part of the code is relevant to you? For overlaying the fragments on top of each other, I used the FragmentManager and fragment BackStack.

Comment: the part where you add the new fragment. You are keeping the old one in the screen?

Comment: @jonathanrz Yes, currently for the demo it is kept in the screen. In edit the related code. I feel that it's a bad idea memory-wise though.

Comment: well, I don´t think that it has an easy response. It will depend of how much views your fragments have and others data that the fragment class have. The best way is always that you let the framework manages memory for you, so the idea of activities will do it. But if you are sure that your fragments use low memory and it is important for you, I don´t think that it will be a problem.

Comment: I found a post of @CommonsWare about how android manages app memory. Maybe changing for activities you not changed anything: https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html